# How to send Body Data to GET Method Request Android

Tags: android, android-volley

[image]

like this, I want to send JSON body request to GET API.

Tried this but it did not work:

```
 public static void getQuestionsListApi2(final String requestId, final String timestamp,
                                        final ImageProcessingCallback.downloadQuestionsCallbacks callback,
                                        final Context context) {

    try {
       String url = NetUrls.downloadQuestions;

        final JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("requestId", requestId);
        jsonBody.put("timestamp", timestamp);
        final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();
        Log.i("params", String.valueOf(jsonBody));
        Log.i("URL", url);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, **jsonBody**, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                Log.v("TAG", "Success " + jsonObject);
                callback.downloadQuestionsCallbacksSuccess(jsonObject.toString());
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.v("TAG", "ERROR " + volleyError.toString());
            }


        });

        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        queue.add(request);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        queue.add(request);
```

Here is the code that I am using when sending `JSONRequest`. with GET method I am getting 400 error response from server **and server does not accept the the data in the URL form**. I am sending The `jsonBody` object as parameter. Any solution?

Comment: it is easy to used retrofit for api call.

Comment: @android-team, any example in retrofit how can we send json body to get method in android?

Comment: is your server live? can you provide url for questions here?

Comment: Yes My Server is Live now for security reason the url in the screen shot has been changed

Comment: I am facing same Issues. Any body solve that issues using Retorfit ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass Json data in body of GET request, you have to use Query annotation

```
Call<YourNodelClass> getSomeDetails(@Query("threaded") String threaded, @Query("limit") int limit);
```

this will pass as Json object `{"threaded": "val", "limit": 3}`.

i have tried and this one is only working code.

Comment: Well, I think this isn't the correct solution because the server will get the data in `query` not in `body`.

Comment: you think and i have tried. please check it will surely work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use retrofit to send request with body. http://square.github.io/retrofit/

It is easy to use library, example:

```
@GET("[url node]")
Single<Response<ResponseBody>> doSmt(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Body ListRequest name);
```

Also, take a look here about get methods with body
[HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

#### UPDATE

GET method with request body is optional [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_method). However, [this RFC7231 document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-24) says,

> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

which means this isn't recommended. Use POST method to use request body.

Check this table from wikipedia.

[image: Table from wikipedia with http methods]

Comment: I am using Volley Library for  now so there is any method in  volley to achieve this.

Comment: This is not the solution. GET annotation can't use with Body annotation in retrofit.